# Looping function in Unity3D (0+1 = 2)?

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine

I might have a little bit trouble I am assuming just a simple
mistake but yet I can not find the the solution well even worse the mistake,
now what I am trying to do is to load all file in my folder by looping it until the max number reached

```
IEnumerator loadData()
{
    Debug.Log (loadNum);
    if (File.Exists (Application.persistentDataPath + "/data[" + loadNum + "].octa")) {
        BinaryFormatter loadData = new BinaryFormatter ();
        FileStream dataFile = File.Open (Application.persistentDataPath + "/data[" + loadNum + "].octa", FileMode.Open);
        playerData pData = (playerData)loadData.Deserialize (dataFile);
        dataFile.Close ();

        name_O = pData.name;
        job_O = pData.job;
        difficulty_O = pData.difficulty;

        rawAPD = name_O + "/" + job_O.ToString() + "/" + difficulty_O.ToString();
        APD = new string[loadNum += 1];

        for (var i = 0; i <= loadNum && i < loadNum; i++) 
        {
            if (APD [i] == null)
            {
                APD [i] = rawAPD;
            }

            break;
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
        if (loadNum != numOfSaveFile_O) 
        {
            Debug.Log ("meh");
            loadNum += 1;
            reLoop ();
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        if (loadNum != numOfSaveFile_O) 
        {
            loadNum += 1;
            reLoop ();  
        }
    }
}

void reLoop()
{
    StartCoroutine (loadData ());
}
```

now everything work great as expected after the yield thing
the number jumps from 0 to 2
the scenario here is I do have `data[0]` and `data[1]` file in my persistent data path

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kC0cC.png)

Comment: What exactly is the question here? If everything works as expected... why are you asking for help?

Comment: Your looping structure seems...overly complex. Why aren't you iterating until a condition is true and yielding results along the way, if that's what you actually want to do? Aside from that, it's pretty unclear what you're actually asking, and your code references all sorts of state that isn't actually in the question - you should probably consider creating a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates problem instead of posting this snippet of your application.

Comment: Pretty sure this is your problem: `APD = new string[loadNum += 1]`, but you also have, `loadNum += 1;`. As an aside I didn't know you could assign variables inside the array declaration, but I just tested it and it works.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen every thing didnt seem as planned it skips number 1 from 0 to 2 for no reason

Comment: @PrestonGuillot im actually having problem why it is skipping number 1, its not really a complex logarithm its just a simple loading mechanism, it will stop looping when the max reached

Comment: @Quantic APD = new string[loadNum += 1] this is just to add one element in the array so i can input data in the array so it wont be array out of index

Comment: @anonymouscoder, no, `APD = new string[loadNum + 1]` makes the array one element larger than `loadNum`; you have `+=`, not `+`: `APD = new string[loadNum += 1]`, so you are *also* inadvertently adding one to `loadNum` as well. Your code is equivalent to this currently: `APD = new string[loadNum =  loadNum + 1]`, and C# happily adds 1 to the `loadNum` variable, then uses that new value when creating the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to do is to load all file in my folder by looping it until
>   the max number reached.

Your code doesn't look good at-all. Lot's of memory allocation and unnecessary repeated coroutine function calls. Simply use `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles()` to get all path of the files in the directory then store it in an array.

I don't know what `APD` is but from what you are doing, you have to initialize the size with the number of items `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles()` returned before the for loop.

You can then use `for` loop to go over arrays and Read the files. Simply call the function below once.

```
IEnumerator loadData()
{
    string fileDir = Application.persistentDataPath;

    //Get All Files Path in in the Directory
    string[] filePath = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(fileDir);

    //Initialize APD with the number of items in filePath
    APD = new string[filePath.Length];

    //Loop through them and read what's in there
    for (int i = 0; i < filePath.Length; i++)
    {
        if ((i + 1) % 5 == 0)
        {
            yield return null;// Wait every after 5 file read
        }

        BinaryFormatter loadData = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream dataFile = File.Open(filePath[i], FileMode.Open); //Open File
        playerData pData = (playerData)loadData.Deserialize(dataFile);
        dataFile.Close();

        name_O = pData.name;
        job_O = pData.job;
        difficulty_O = pData.difficulty;

        rawAPD = name_O + "/" + job_O.ToString() + "/" + difficulty_O.ToString();
        APD[i] = rawAPD;
    }
}
```

If you only want to read files from `1` to `numOfSaveFile_O` with `.octa` extension instead of all files in the Folder, then below is what your code should look like. This assumes that your files are named like `data[0].octa`, `data[1].octa`,`data[2].octa`,`data[3].octa`....

```
IEnumerator loadData2()
{
    string fileDir = Application.persistentDataPath;
    int APDIndex = 0; //Only incremented if file exist

    APD = new string[numOfSaveFile_O];
    loadNum = 0; //File starts at 0

    while (loadNum < numOfSaveFile_O)
    {
        string filePath = fileDir + "/data[" + loadNum + "].octa";

        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            Debug.Log(loadNum);

            BinaryFormatter loadData = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream dataFile = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open); //Open File
            playerData pData = (playerData)loadData.Deserialize(dataFile);
            dataFile.Close();

            name_O = pData.name;
            job_O = pData.job;
            difficulty_O = pData.difficulty;

            rawAPD = name_O + "/" + job_O.ToString() + "/" + difficulty_O.ToString();
            APD[APDIndex] = rawAPD;
            APDIndex++;
        }
        loadNum++;
        yield return null; //Don't freeze Unity
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the comments it appears this is what you need; change this:

`APD = new string[loadNum += 1];`

to this:

`APD = new string[loadNum + 1];`