# How to check for string endings for loading save files?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to know how to check for the endings of all the files in the Assets folder. 
Its for creating a list of saved files.

```
public static void Load()
{
    if (File.Exists(Application.dataPath + "/data1.sav"))
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Open(Application.dataPath + "/data1.sav", FileMode.Open);
        SaveLoad.savedData = (List<saveData>)bf.Deserialize(file);
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

^this load function works fine.
Now i need something like this:

(pseudocode)

```
if (File.Exists(With the ending: ".sav") ???? 
{
 Create a list of all those files in a String Array!
}
```

so if i would have in the Assets folder:
"data1.sav"
"data2.sav"
"test.sav" it should return a String Array with the 
size of 3 and which include ["data1.sav"], ["data2.sav"] and ["test.sav"]

Comment: A verify similar question with this http://stackoverflow.com/a/38213646/3785314 Just use `Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryPath, "*.sav");` like the answer below then put your `if (File.Exists(With the ending: ".sav") 
{

}` code in a for loop and loop over each index result.

Answer (score 3):

Just use [GetFiles()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Code would be something like:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryPath, "*.sav");
```